# Pow server - my site need port number for .dev

Tags: ruby, port

there, I am new to Ruby and trying to use Pow in my Mac.

When I type MYSITE.dev/ in my browser, it always says "The connection was reset". But it works fine for MYSITE.dev:20559. It seems that I can't just go to MYSITE.dev. I have to also add my port number, MYSITE.dev:20559.

I've been trying resolve this issue after much searching. I tired the following steps [here](https://github.com/basecamp/pow/issues/366), edited the /Library/LaunchDaemons/cx.pow.firewall.plist file, but it does not work. I tried restarting my computer as well, but nothing working.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to tell the server to run on port 80. And you don't know iptables rules to redirect traffic, although that will work but it's convoluted.

Comment: Well, I reinstalled POW and solved the problem… thanks anyway..